getprocesscpuload() API Returning 0 when calculated at short intervals of 100ms
I am using getProcessCpuLoad() method provided by OperatingSystemMXBean interface (Oracle JDK) to calculate CPU usage of process at periodic interval of 100ms. The process in background is using almost 90% CPU as confirmed with the top command. But this method returns 0, almost 10 times a minute.
Reference doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad()
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;

public class CPUUsage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Get the OperatingSystemMXBean
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        
        // Create a TimerTask
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cpuUsage = (int)(osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100); // Calculate CPU usage
                System.out.println("Current CPU load: " + cpuUsage);
            }
        };
        
        // Schedule the task to run every 100ms
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100);
        
    }
}

Below is the data of the frequency of 0's every minute.
12 05:33 | 5 05:34 | 13 05:35 | 7 05:36 | 12 05:37 | 8 05:38 | 10 05:39 | 2 05:40


Tried replacing getProcessCpuLoad() with getCpuLoad(), still we see 0's returned by the method.

On changing the periodic interval to 300ms, frequency of 0's reduced to 1 time a minute.

On changing the periodic interval to 5s, no 0's observed.


When does getProcessCpuLoad() return zero?
Is there any interval defined after which the API calculates CPU usage, or is there a configuration I might be missing? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.
